# How to control the mousewheel down and up in a div

Tags: javascript, html, mousewheel

i'm making a website for my school and i need to control if the user scrolls the mouse wheel up or down when the mouse is inside a specific div.

f.e.:http://www.apple.com/pt/iphone-5s/

i want to replicate the slide effect but only in a small portion of the page(the div i spoke of). so how do i control this in javascript? there is no need to find out how much he scrolls, he will only be able to scroll through one slide at a time, just the scroll itself.

Comment: Stack Overflow will NOT do your homework. What have you tried?

Comment: he didn't say it was homework. sound's like he's showing initiative and actually making a school website

Comment: @codingaround this is not my homework, i'm getting paid for it... yes i have tried but unsucessfully that's why i asked here. to get new opinions...

Comment: That's okay. Then show us the problematic portions of code if there are any.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

the second one is probably the one you want.  You can check for the wheel events then check the mouse cursor position. or something like that.   However, you need to consider people will access your page with tablets etc, so really scrollwheel events depending on "mouse position" is actually not a great idea.

Comment: thanks, it helped. as for tablets and phone i'll be making a mobile version as well wich will not have this scrolling option. thanks again :D

Comment: good luck on the project!